# What is the difference between "npm install" and "npm ci"?

Tags: npm, continuous-integration, npm-install, npm-ci

I'm working with continuous integration and discovered the [npm ci](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ci) command.

I can't figure what the advantages are of using this command for my workflow.

Is it faster?  Does it make the test harder, okay, and after?

Answer (score 1000, accepted):

From [the official documentation for npm ci](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ci):

> In short, the main differences between using npm install and npm ci are:
>
> - The project must have an existing package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json.
> - If dependencies in the package lock do not match those in package.json, npm ci will exit with an error, instead of updating the package lock.
> - npm ci can only install entire projects at a time: individual dependencies cannot be added with this command.
> - If a node_modules is already present, it will be automatically removed before npm ci begins its install.
> - It will never write to package.json or any of the package-locks: installs are essentially frozen.

---

Essentially,
**`npm install`** reads `package.json` to create a list of dependencies and uses `package-lock.json` to inform which versions of these dependencies to install. **If a dependency is not in `package-lock.json` it will be added by `npm install`**.

**`npm ci`** (also known as **C**lean **I**nstall) is meant to be used in automated environments — such as test platforms, continuous integration, and deployment — or, any situation where you want to make sure you're doing a clean install of your dependencies.

It installs dependencies directly from `package-lock.json` and uses `package.json` only to validate that there are no mismatched versions. **If any dependencies are missing or have incompatible versions, it will throw an error**.

Use `npm install` to add new dependencies, and to update dependencies on a project. Usually, you would use it during development after pulling changes that update the list of dependencies but it may be a good idea to use `npm ci` in this case.

Use `npm ci` if you need a deterministic, repeatable build. For example during continuous integration, automated jobs, etc. and when installing dependencies for the first time, instead of `npm install`.

### [`npm install`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install.html)

- Installs a package and all its dependencies.
- Dependencies are driven by `npm-shrinkwrap.json` and `package-lock.json` (in that order).
- **without arguments**: installs dependencies of a local module.
- Can install global packages.
- Will install any missing dependencies in `node_modules`.
- It may write to `package.json` or `package-lock.json`.

  - When used with an argument (`npm i packagename`) it may write to `package.json` to add or update the dependency.
  - when used without arguments, (`npm i`) it may write to `package-lock.json` to lock down the version of some dependencies if they are not already in this file.

### [`npm ci`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ci)

- Requires at least npm [v5.7.1](https://github.com/npm/npm/releases/tag/v5.7.1).
- Requires `package-lock.json` or `npm-shrinkwrap.json` to be present.
- Throws an error if dependencies from these two files don't match `package.json`.
- Removes `node_modules` and install *all dependencies* at once.
- It never writes to `package.json` or `package-lock.json`.

### Algorithm

While `npm ci` generates the entire dependency tree from `package-lock.json` or `npm-shrinkwrap.json`, `npm install` *updates the contents of `node_modules`* using the following algorithm ([source](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install#algorithm)):

> ```
> load the existing node_modules tree from disk
> clone the tree
> fetch the package.json and assorted metadata and add it to the clone
> walk the clone and add any missing dependencies
>   dependencies will be added as close to the top as is possible
>   without breaking any other modules
> compare the original tree with the cloned tree and make a list of
> actions to take to convert one to the other
> execute all of the actions, deepest first
>   kinds of actions are install, update, remove and move
> ```

Comment: I didn't know `npm install` could write to package.json. Do you know what it could write in here?

Comment: well that might be a bit misleading... it will write to package.json when you use it to install, update, or remove dependencies. I'll make that more clear in the text, thanks!

Comment: `npm install package` could modify both `package-lock.json` **and** `package.json`, while `npm install` whithout arguments would only modify `package-lock.json`

Comment: Recently, I have found that if we want npm not to install missing dependencies from `package-lock.json`, we can rewrite `"require": true"` in  `package-lock.json`.

Comment: How the cache works? Will it be slower or faster if compare with old way by `npm install`?

Comment: I believe that one of the differences is also that `npm install` installs `devDependencies` while `npm ci` does not, as far as I understand.

Comment: @Link14 installation of `devDependencies` is controlled by the `--production` flag or the `NODE_ENV` environment variable, for both `npm i` and `npm ci`

Comment: While not explicitly said anywhere in the docs, the `ci` in `npm ci` is better understood as clean install and not continuous integration.

Comment: What about using both, firebase hosting defualts to both for the build command

Comment: I don't think this `Removes node_modules and install all dependencies at once.`is the case, or at least in 2022 npm ci install `node_modules` as welll as

Comment: My similar [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64014814/10788155) shows a comparison in a tabular way.

Comment: "[npm ci] uses package.json only to validate that there are no mismatched versions" -- This does not seem to be 100% correct: The package.json also seems to influence dependency resolution. I just ran into a case where, in the absence of `package.json` (I had forgotten to add it to my Docker image), `npm ci` exited with an error `npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve […] Conflicting peer dependency`. After adding the `package.json` to the Docker image, however, everything worked again.

Comment: You mentioned this but I think it might be nice to call it out. `npm install` has "dependencies will be added as close to the top as is possible" which means they might not be the same dependencies as someone else . `npm ci` doesn't have that issue.  I think (but could be wrong) if I do `npm install foo@1.2.4` but package.json and package-lock.json say to use `foo@^1.2.3` then `npm install` will leave it as is where as `npm ci` will delete `node_modules` and install `foo@1.2.3`.  This hits me when switching between git branches. `npm install` can fail to put things to a working state.

Answer (score 90):

`npm ci` will delete any existing `node_modules` folder and relies on the `package-lock.json` file to install the specific version of each package. It is significantly faster than npm install because it skips some features. Its clean state install is great for ci/cd pipelines and docker builds! You also use it to install everything all at once and not specific packages.

Comment: Deleting a preexisting node_modules might make the build a lot slower

Comment: Maybe don't commit node_modules?

Comment: @jontro, my colleague measured the commands in docker and found that for our package  ci is significantly quicker than install (40 sec vs 130 sec), but YMMV.

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim is that with a pre-existing node_modules or from a clean start?

Comment: @jontro, as I understand dockerfile commands ‘ WORKDIR /src 
COPY src/package.json . 
COPY src/package-lock.json .  
RUN npm ci --no-optional;  ‘  recreate node_modules each time.

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim Well sure. My comment was just to inform about it being slower in case you're not running it from a clean slate. It's a drawback depending on how the setup is.

Comment: This answer is misleading: both `npm i` and `npm ci` use on `package-lock.json`. Many people believe `npm i` ignores `package-lock.json` which is not true. It's also not faster than `npm i` - indeed `npm i` is definitely faster when `node_modules/` exists.

Answer (score 47):

### While everyone else has answered the technical differences none explain in what situations to use both.

You should use them in different situations.

`npm install` is great for development and in the CI when you want to cache the `node_modules` directory.
When to use this? You can do this if you are making a package for other people to use *(you do NOT include `node_modules` in such a release)*. Regarding the caching, be careful, if you plan to support different versions of `Node.js` remember that `node_modules` might have to be reinstalled due to differences between the `Node.js` runtime requirements. If you wish to stick to one version, stick to the latest `LTS`.

`npm ci` should be used when you are to test and release a production application (a final product, not to be used by other packages) since it is important that you have the installation be as deterministic as possible, this install will take longer but will ultimately make your application more reliable *(you do include `node_modules` in such a release)*. Stick with `LTS` version of `Node.js`.

`npm i` and `npm ci` both utilize the npm cache if it exists, this cache lives normally at `~/.npm`.

Also, `npm ci` respects the `package-lock.json` file. Unlike `npm install`, which rewrites the file and always installs new versions.

*Bonus: You could mix them depending on how complex you want to make it. On feature branches in `git` you could cache the `node_modules` to increase your teams productivity and on the merge request and master branches rely on `npm ci` for a deterministic outcome.*

Comment: I don't think that there is any scenario where `npm i` should be used over `npm ci` except when you want to update your dependencies. `npm ci` is always better because deterministic behaviour is always better

Comment: @enanone As I stated `npm i` caches as it is quicker, `npm ci` is slower since it does a full reinstall. They are both useful.

Comment: `npm ci` is just as fast if every package is in the npm cache

Comment: In my case, `npm ci` is significantly slower even when done repeatedly, with a local NPM cache: `npm install` is about 2s, `npm ci` 16s when run for the same project. After a cache clear they're the same. We desperately need something that would install from package-lock but don't start by deleting node_modules: https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/564

Comment: @Piedone I'd say deleting `node_modules` is a feature as I've seen it happen that developers had some custom changes in there and were wondering why it wouldn't work on production. I always prefer a command having repeatedly the exact same outcome over the seemingly faster one. Yet just the fact that `npm install` might mutate the `package-lock.json` is a really bad default for a dependency manager and also is a huge win for `npm ci`. I always use `ci` for pure installation even on my development machine, and `install` only for when I want to update or add a new dependency.

Comment: @basickarl, should npm ci also be used by other developers on the project if they aren't messing around with the package.json, and only use npm install when you are actually modifying the package.json? So if there are changes to package.json, you tell everyone "btw, run npm ci after you pull the latest changes"? My issue (due to lack of my understanding) has been that everyone on the project tends to run npm install, and then the package-lock always has a merge conflicts, which seems to defeat the purpose of having the lock in the first place.

Comment: @JarrodMcGuire What I normally end up doing which merge conflicts is I run a fresh npm install then let that generated lock-file overwrite both of the other ones (since it is the latest generation of it and hence has the most recent updated file packages). But make sure to run your test suites immediately after generating the new package-lock so that nothing explodes.

Answer (score 30):

- `npm ci` - install exactly what is listed in package-lock.json
- `npm install` - without changing any versions in package.json, use package.json to write package-lock.json, then install exactly what is listed in package-lock.json
- `npm update` - similar to `npm install` but will also install updates for "blurred version" stuff (e.g. `*`, `^1.2.3`)
- `npx npm-check-updates -u; npm install` - Will try to update absolutely everything to the latest version. Be careful of breaking changes when using this one.

Or said a different way, `npm ci` changes 0 package files, `npm install` and `npm update` change 1 package file (package-lock.json), and `npx npm-check-updates -u; npm install` changes 2 package files (package.json and package-lock.json).

Answer (score 9):

The documentation you linked had the summary:

> In short, the main differences between using npm install and npm ci are:
>
> - The project must have an existing package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json.
> - If dependencies in the package lock do not match those in package.json, npm ci will exit with an error, instead of updating the package lock.
> - npm ci can only install entire projects at a time: individual dependencies cannot be added with this command.
> - If a node_modules is already present, it will be automatically removed before npm ci begins its install.
> - It will never write to package.json or any of the package-locks: installs are essentially frozen.

Answer (score 7):

The commands are very similar in functionality however the difference is in the approach taken to install the dependencies specified in your `package.json` and `package-lock.json` files.

`npm ci` performs a clean install of all the dependencies of your app whereas `npm install` may skip some installations if they already exist on the system. A problem may arise if the version already installed on the system isn't the one your `package.json` intended to install i.e. the installed version is different from the '*required*' version.

Other differences would be that `npm ci` never touches your `package*.json` files. It will stop installation and show an error if the dependency versions do not match in the `package.json` and `package-lock.json` files.

You can read a much better explanation from the official docs [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ci.html).

Additionally, you may want to read about package locks [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package-locks).

Answer (score 5):

It is worth having in mind that light node docker images like alpine do not have Python installed which is a dependency of `node-gyp` which is used by `npm ci`.

I think it's a bit opinionated that in order to have `npm ci` working you need to install Python as dependency in your build.

More info here [Docker and npm - gyp ERR! not ok](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59634089/docker-and-npm-gyp-err-not-ok)

Comment: From what question you posted they are having an issue with `react-scripts` not due to `npm ci` from what I can find there no dependency on `python` in `npm ci`

Answer (score 2):

It does a clean install, use it in situations where you would delete node_modules and re-run `npm i`.

I have no idea why some people think it's short for "continuous integration". There is an `npm install` command that can be run as `npm i` and an `npm clean-install` command that can be run as `npm ci`.

Answer (score 1):

npm install is the command used to install the dependencies listed in a project's package.json file, while npm ci is a command that installs dependencies from a package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json file. The npm ci command is typically used in continuous integration (CI) environments, where the package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json file is checked into version control and should not be modified. Because npm ci installs dependencies from a locked file, it is a faster and more reliable way to install dependencies than npm install, which could install different versions of dependencies based on the state of the package.json file.