# Docker and npm - gyp ERR! not ok

Tags: node.js, docker, npm

Everything was working with my client until I tried to solve some *Network disconnected* issue by upgrading `react-scripts` in my `docker` client service from `3.0.1` to `3.3.0`, using `npm install <package> --save` and building it again.

But then it started to complain requiring `css-loader` and `style-loader`, and I installed them. Then it did not work and I reverted my setup back to `3.0.1`, uninstalling both previous packages with `--save` flag in order to remove it from `node_modules/` as well.

Now, when I run `docker-compose -f docker-compose-dev.yml build client`, I get the following error, *although client service is built*:

```
> fsevents@1.2.11 install /usr/src/app/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents
> node-gyp rebuild

gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@11.12.0 | linux | x64
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:484:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:406:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at F (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:68:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at E (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:158:21)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.9.184-linuxkit
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/src/app/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v11.12.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 

> core-js@3.6.4 postinstall /usr/src/app/node_modules/core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

Thank you for using core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock/core-js ) for polyfilling JavaScript standard library!

The project needs your help! Please consider supporting of core-js on Open Collective or Patreon: 
> https://opencollective.com/core-js 
> https://www.patreon.com/zloirock 

Also, the author of core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock ) is looking for a good job -)


> fsevents@1.2.11 install /usr/src/app/node_modules/jest-haste-map/node_modules/fsevents
> node-gyp rebuild

gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@11.12.0 | linux | x64
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:484:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:406:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at F (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:68:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at E (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:158:21)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.9.184-linuxkit
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/src/app/node_modules/jest-haste-map/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v11.12.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
```

---

This is my **docker-compose-dev.yml**:

```
web:
    build:
      context: ./services/web
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-dev
    volumes:
      - './services/web:/usr/src/app'

    ports:
      - 5001:5000
    environment:
      - FLASK_ENV=development
      - APP_SETTINGS=brandio.config.DevelopmentConfig
      - DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:postgres@web-db:5432/web_dev 
      - DATABASE_TEST_URL=postgres://postgres:postgres@web-db:5432/web_test
      - SECRET_KEY=my_precious
    depends_on:  
      - web-db
      - redis

client:
    build:
      context: ./services/client
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-dev
    volumes:
      - './services/client:/usr/src/app'
      - '/usr/src/app/node_modules'
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
      - REACT_APP_WEB_SERVICE_URL=${REACT_APP_WEB_SERVICE_URL}
    depends_on:
      - web
```

---

This is my **client** **Dockerfile**:

```
# base image
FROM node:11.12.0-alpine

# set working directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# add `/usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install and cache app dependencies
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/package.json
COPY package-lock.json /usr/src/app/package-lock.json
RUN npm ci
RUN npm install react-scripts@3.3.0 -g --silent

# start app
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

---

**web** service **Dockerfile**, which client depends on. I have tried to install `node-gyp`in the env, and `python` is certainly here. To no avail:

```
FROM python:3.7-slim-buster

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y dist-upgrade 
RUN apt-get -y install node-gyp build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev libblas3 libc6 liblapack3 gcc python3-dev 
RUN apt install -y netcat

# set working directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY ./requirements.txt /usr/src/app/requirements.txt 
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

# add entrypoint.sh
COPY ./entrypoint.sh /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh

RUN chmod +x /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh

# add app
COPY . /usr/src/app

# run server
CMD ["/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

**Package.json**:

```
    {
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.1",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-alert": "^5.5.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.5.3",
    "react-html-parser": "^2.0.2",
    "react-player": "^1.13.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "^3.3.0",
    "react-transition-group": "^2.9.0",
    "spotify-web-api-js": "^1.2.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.2"
  }
}
```

---

Now it is back to `3.3.0`, but problem persists.

---

`$ npm list` shows me problems with peer dependencies:

```
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @types/react@^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0, required by react-hot-loader@4.12.18
npm ERR! peer dep missing: typescript@^3.2.1, required by react-scripts@3.3.0
npm ERR! peer dep missing: node-sass@^4.0.0, required by sass-loader@8.0.0
npm ERR! peer dep missing: sass@^1.3.0, required by sass-loader@8.0.0
npm ERR! peer dep missing: fibers@>= 3.1.0, required by sass-loader@8.0.0
npm ERR! peer dep missing: typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta, required by tsutils@3.17.1
npm ERR! peer dep missing: typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta, required by tsutils@3.17.1
```

I don't know if issues are related.

---

I have also installed `node-gyp` globally, tested, error persisted and then I uninstalled again.

---

How do I fix this?

Comment: looks like the container `node:11.12.0-alpine` does not have a python distribution installed

Comment: I don't get it. it was working for months with this precise setup.

Comment: Maybe, but I don't see anything in that dockerfile that installs Python, so if it worked before, that's kind of miraculous. The solutions I work with have two dockerfiles, one for node, and one for python, with a docker-compose.yml that loads both.

Comment: python is installed in `web` service, which client depends on. does this makes sense?

Comment: it does not: at least not without additional information on where you've defined that `web` task, and what's in it.

Comment: please refer to edit

Comment: Did you edit your web dockerfile? `# FROM python:3.6-alpine` is commented off, so it's a good bet `FROM alpine:3.7` doesn't actually work. The one I use on a daily basis uses `FROM python:3.7-slim`.

Comment: It was working, believe me. This was edited out for at least 6 months, rebuilt, and client was working like a charm since then. It broke only when I did the npm installs, yesterday

Comment: What command exactly leads to error? And why you think this command is related to Docker?

Comment: this command: `docker-compose -f docker-compose-dev.yml build client`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Add the following line to your client Dockerfile:

```
RUN apk update && apk add python make g++
```

So it should look like this:

```
# base image
FROM node:11.12.0-alpine

RUN apk update && apk add python make g++

# set working directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# add `/usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install and cache app dependencies
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/package.json
COPY package-lock.json /usr/src/app/package-lock.json
RUN npm ci
RUN npm install react-scripts@3.3.0 -g --silent

# start app
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Comment: my web image is `python3.7`. should it not be add `python3` here?

Comment: The recommended change is for the client docker file not the web docker file.
The python is needed to rebuild the node-gyp module.
This python has nothing to do with the python in your web docker.

Comment: I find interesting that in order to have `npm ci` working in your ci/cd you need python as dependency.

Comment: Why do put this line: `ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH` ? I have read other posts where there no this command.