# Can't build Angular project after upgrade from 8 to 9

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, docker

I've done an upgrade of my Angular project from 8 to 9 by using the `ng update` tool. Locally (Windows) everything works fine, but when I'm trying to build the project in docker, I get the following error:

```
Step 6/11 : RUN npm run build
  ---> Running in d60f739a56f6
 > check-it-frontend@0.0.0 build /app
 > ng build --prod
 Compiling @angular/core : es2015 as esm2015
 ERROR in EINVAL: invalid argument, rename '/app/node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts' -> '/app/node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts.__ivy_ngcc_bak'
 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
 npm ERR! errno 1
 npm ERR! check-it-frontend@0.0.0 build: `ng build --prod`
 npm ERR! Exit status 1
 npm ERR! 
 npm ERR! Failed at the check-it-frontend@0.0.0 build script.
 npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
 npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-03-20T11_44_02_696Z-debug.log
 The command '/bin/sh -c npm run build' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

The dockerfile:

```
FROM node:13.10.1-stretch as base

RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential

ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN npm ci
RUN npm run build
```

Dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/animations": "^9.0.7",
  "@angular/cdk": "^8.2.3",
  "@angular/common": "^9.0.7",
  "@angular/compiler": "^9.0.7",
  "@angular/core": "^9.0.7",
  "@angular/forms": "^9.0.7",
  "@angular/material": "^8.2.3",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "^9.0.7",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^9.0.7",
  "@angular/router": "^9.0.7",
  "core-js": "^2.4.1",
  "rxjs": "^6.5.4",
  "rxjs-compat": "^6.0.0-rc.0",
  "tslib": "^1.10.0",
  "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.900.7",
  "@angular/cli": "^9.0.7",
  "@angular/compiler-cli": "^9.0.7",
  "@angular/language-service": "^9.0.7",
  "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
  "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
  "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
  "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
  "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
  "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
  "karma": "~2.0.0",
  "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
  "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
  "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
  "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
  "node-sass": "^4.13.1",
  "protractor": "~5.1.2",
  "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
  "tslint": "~5.9.1",
  "typescript": "~3.7.5"
}
```

Anything I can do to fix it? Images for Angular 8 were fine. I've tried different node images, but nothing helped...

Comment: When I was installing cli via `npm install`, the `ng` command wasn't present. I've fixed the explicit older version in my dockerfile, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not node dev so I didn't know about the `npm run` and `npm ci`. Anyway, it still raises the same error after the change.

Comment: @Djent [What is the difference between “npm install” and “npm ci”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52499617/what-is-the-difference-between-npm-install-and-npm-ci)

Comment: Have you tried to delete all `node_modules` and reinstall it by npm i ?

Comment: It's a fresh docker container - there's no `node_modules` yet.

Comment: Can you try adding `"postinstall": "ngcc"` in your `package.json` file?

Comment: @David - that helped, thanks! You may want to post it as an answer to get the bounty reward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what your issue is or what's causing it, but I did a quick search and stumbled upon this [github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/32431). It concerns parallel builds (which I don't think is your case), but I thought it could still apply here since the error happens during the compilation of angular core.

The suggested workaround is to run the angular compatibility compiler (`ngcc`) as a `postinstall` script, instead of having the build trigger it itself.

Modify your `package.json` file and add the following to the `scripts` section:

```
"postinstall": "ngcc
```

Comment: For info: https://angular.io/guide/ivy#ivy-and-universalapp-shell