# Caching npm dependencies in circleci

Tags: node.js, npm, caching, circleci, circleci-2.0

I'm setting up the CI for an existing Express server project that lives in my repo's backend/core folder. Starting with just basic setup and linting. I was able to get npm install and linting to work but I wanted to cache the dependencies so that it wouldn't take 4 minutes to load for each push.

I used the caching scheme they describe [here](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/caching/) but it still seemed to run the full install each time. Or if it was using cached dependencies, it installed grpc each time which took a while. Any ideas what I can do?

My config.yml for reference:

```yaml
# Use the latest 2.1 version of CircleCI pipeline process engine. See: https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference

# default executors
executors:
  core-executor:
    docker:
      - image: 'cimg/base:stable'

commands:
  init_env:
    description: initialize environment
    steps:
      - checkout
      - node/install
      - restore_cache:
          keys:
            # when lock file changes, use increasingly general patterns to restore cache
            - node-v1-{{ .Branch }}-{{ checksum "backend/core/package-lock.json" }}
            - node-v1-{{ .Branch }}-
            - node-v1-

      - run: npm --prefix ./backend/core install

      - save_cache:
          paths:
            - ~/backend/core/usr/local/lib/node_modules  # location depends on npm version
          key: node-v1-{{ .Branch }}-{{ checksum "backend/core/package-lock.json" }}


jobs:
  install-node:
    executor: core-executor
    steps:
      - checkout
      - node/install
      - run: node --version
      - run: pwd
      - run: ls -A
      - run: npm --prefix ./backend/core install

  lint:
    executor: core-executor
    steps:
      - init_env
      - run: pwd
      - run: ls -A
      - run: ls backend
      - run: ls backend/core -A
      - run: npm --prefix ./backend/core run lint

orbs:
  node: circleci/node@4.1.0
version: 2.1
workflows:
  test_my_app:
    jobs:
      #- install-node
      - lint
          #requires:
            #- install-node
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the best thing to do is to use `npm ci` which is faster. Best explanation of this is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53325242/4410223. Even though it will reinstall every time, it is consistent so better than caching. Although when using this, I am unsure what the point of continuing to use cache in your pipeline is, but caching still seems to be recommended with `npm ci`.

However, the best way to do this is to just use the node orb you already have in your config. A single step of `- node/install-packages` will do all that work for you. You will be able to replace it with your `restore_cache`, `npm install` and `save_cache` steps. You can even see all the steps it does here: https://circleci.com/developer/orbs/orb/circleci/node#commands-install-packages. Just open the command source and look at the steps on line 71.

Comment: I second the approach to use the `circleci/node` orb. It will automatically take care of caching. The key is to not cache the newly added `node_modules` dir, but to cache the npm local cache. For example: `/home/circleci/.npm`. `npm ci` will delete your `node_modules` dir, but it will quickly rebuild it from the npm local cache.