# npm install doesn't apply what is in package-lock.json?

Tags: npm, package-lock.json

I have Node v10.22.0, npm 6.14.6, on MacOS Catalina.

I start from a git repo that contains a `package-lock.json` that specifies `@truffle` dependencies and no `node_modules` folder, no `package.json`. After I cloned the repo, I run `npm install` to install dependencies. The npm doc says

> If the package has a package-lock ..., the installation of
> dependencies will be driven by that

Surprisingly it actually installs 8 packages that have nothing to do with my project: `d`, `es5-ext`, `es6-iterator`, `es6-symbol`, `ext`, `next-tick`, `type` **AND** it overwrites `package-lock.json` with a new one containing dependencies on these 8 packages.

If I overwrite `package-lock.json` and launch `npm install`, it redoes the same trick.

Questions:

1. what is happening?
2. how can I make `npm install` populate `node_modules` correctly?

Comment: Also note that npm will "promote" packages to the root during install if they are predominant and used by multiple dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

Use `npm ci` to install dependencies based on your lock file. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52499617/what-is-the-difference-between-npm-install-and-npm-ci) for more details about this command, it has the answer to your questions.

Comment: Cool. Thanks a lot. I was relying too much on the `npm install` docs. It has not been updated after `npm ci` was introduced, probably.

My work around was to create a `package.json` and not rely on `package-lock.json`

But i'm still puzzled to know where `npm install` found the instructions that made it install these curious 8 packages and overwrite `package-lock.json`