# Is there any difference between running rm -rf node_modules + npm i vs npm ci?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

If I'm using a unix system and want to clear out my node modules folder, is there any difference or advantage to running

`rm -rf node_modules`

then
`npm i`

versus

`npm ci`

As I understand it they're producing the same result, but is what's going on under the hood the same?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52499617/what-is-the-difference-between-npm-install-and-npm-ci

Comment: ^ this is not what I asked - I'm talking about running rm -rf node_modules before running npm i and if that's the same as npm ci

Answer (score 0):

Running `npm help ci` will give you the answer; in short it removes the node_modules as well but it's meant for the CI so some additional tasks are performed:

> This command is similar to `npm install`, except it's meant to be used in automated environments such as test platforms, continuous integration, and deployment or any situation where you want to make sure you're doing a clean install of your dependencies. It can be significantly faster than a regular `npm install` by skipping certain user-oriented features. It is also more strict than a regular install, which can help catch errors or inconsistencies caused by the incrementally-installed local environments of most npm users.
>
> In short, the main differences between using npm install and npm ci are:
>
> - The project must have an existing package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json.
> - If dependencies in the package lock do not match those in package.json, npm ci will exit with an error, instead of updating the package lock.
> - npm ci can only install entire projects at a time: individual dependencies cannot be added with this command.
> - If a node_modules is already present, it will be automatically removed before npm ci begins its install.
> - It will never write to package.json or any of the package-locks: installs are essentially frozen.