# web3 install fails due to Insecure Credential Storage and Insecure Credential Storage

Tags: npm, web3js

Installing latest web3 version 1.3.5 on Ubuntu with npm version 7.12.0 fails with a couple of high severity errors. What is typical time-frame for a fix?

## npm audit report

> underscore  1.3.2 - 1.12.0
> Severity: high
> Arbitrary Code Execution - [https://npmjs.com/advisories/1674\](https://npmjs.com/advisories/1674%5C)
> No fix available
> node_modules/underscore
> ..web3-bzz  <=1.3.5
> ..Depends on vulnerable versions of underscore
> ..node_modules/web3-bzz
> ....web3  *
> ....Depends on vulnerable versions of web3-bzz
> ....Depends on vulnerable versions of web3-eth
> ....node_modules/web3
> ..web3-core-helpers  *
> ..Depends on vulnerable versions of underscore
> ..node_modules/web3-core-helpers
> ....web3-eth-ens  *
> ....Depends on vulnerable versions of underscore
> ....Depends on vulnerable versions of web3-core-helpers
> ....node_modules/web3-eth-ens
> ......web3-eth  *
> ......Depends on vulnerable versions of underscore
> ......Depends on vulnerable versions of web3-eth-ens
> ......node_modules/web3-eth
> ....web3-providers-http  *
> ....Depends on vulnerable versions of web3-core-helpers
> ....node_modules/web3-providers-http
> ..web3-core-method  *
> ..Depends on vulnerable versions of underscore
> ..node_modules/web3-core-method
> ....web3-core  *
> ....Depends on vulnerable versions of web3-core-method
> ....node_modules/web3-core
> ....web3-eth-personal  *
> ....Depends on vulnerable versions of web3-core-method
> ....Depends on vulnerable versions of web3-net
> ....node_modules/web3-eth-personal
> ....web3-net  <=1.0.0-beta.55 || >=1.2.0
> ....Depends on vulnerable versions of web3-core-method
> ....node_modules/web3-net
> ......web3-shh  <=1.3.5
> ......Depends on vulnerable versions of web3-core-method
> ......Depends on vulnerable versions of web3-net
> ......node_modules/web3-shh
> ..web3-core-requestmanager  *
> ..Depends on vulnerable versions of underscore
> ..node_modules/web3-core-requestmanager
> ..web3-core-subscriptions  *
> ..Depends on vulnerable versions of underscore
> ..node_modules/web3-core-subscriptions
> ..web3-eth-abi  *
> ..Depends on vulnerable versions of underscore
> ..node_modules/web3-eth-abi
> ..web3-eth-accounts  *
> ..Depends on vulnerable versions of underscore
> ..node_modules/web3-eth-accounts
> ..web3-eth-contract  *
> ..Depends on vulnerable versions of underscore
> ..node_modules/web3-eth-contract
> ..web3-providers-ipc  *
> ..Depends on vulnerable versions of underscore
> ..node_modules/web3-providers-ipc
> ..web3-providers-ws  *
> ..Depends on vulnerable versions of underscore
> ..node_modules/web3-providers-ws
> ..web3-utils  >=1.0.0-beta.8
> ..Depends on vulnerable versions of underscore
> ..node_modules/web3-utils
> ....web3-eth-iban  *
> ....Depends on vulnerable versions of web3-utils
> ....node_modules/web3-eth-iban
>
> web3  *
> Severity: high
> Insecure Credential Storage - [https://npmjs.com/advisories/877\](https://npmjs.com/advisories/877%5C)
> Depends on vulnerable versions of web3-bzz
> Depends on vulnerable versions of web3-eth
> No fix available
> node_modules/web3
>
> 21 high severity vulnerabilities\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We run `npm ci && npm audit --audit-level=high` in our project's CI pipeline and we have encountered this underscore issue today.

There's already the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/ChainSafe/web3.js/issues/4049) about it:

We are now waiting for new release (patch). Before that a quick fix and a possible solution would be to search for `underscore` in your *package-lock.json* and to manually update `underscore` version there, because `npm audit fix` won't fix it automatically.

We had 1.9.1 version used and updated to 1.12.1 (which is listed in audit log as a stable one). Kindly change these lines for every *underscore*'s occurrence:

- version: `1.9.1` => `1.12.1`;
- resolved: `https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore/-/underscore-1.9.1.tgz` => `https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore/-/underscore-1.12.1.tgz`;
- integrity: `sha512-5/4etnCkd9c8gwgowi5/om/mYO5ajCaOgdzj/oW+0eQV9WxKBDZw5+ycmKmeaTXjInS/W0BzpGLo2xR2aBwZdg==` => `sha512-hEQt0+ZLDVUMhebKxL4x1BTtDY7bavVofhZ9KZ4aI26X9SRaE+Y3m83XUL1UP2jn8ynjndwCCpEHdUG+9pP1Tw==`.

This way `npm ci` will get versions from *package-lock.json* and no error will occur. But `npm install` will ignore it...

Here's a difference between these 2 commands if needed: [Difference between npm install and npm ci](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53325242/9317057)

**UPDATE**

Also you can use [npm-force-resolutions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-force-resolutions) package in order to set the specific version of *underscore* package:

1. Add `"resolutions": { "underscore": "1.12.1" }` to your *package.json*;
2. Optionally add *preinstall* script that will be run every time before `npm install` starts: `"scripts": { "preinstall": "npx npm-force-resolutions" }`;
3. Run `npm install` or `npx npm-force-resolutions` and see your changes in *package-lock.json*. Also `npm audit` won't find those vulnerabilities.

**FINAL UPDATE**

[web3@1.3.6](https://github.com/ChainSafe/web3.js/releases/tag/v1.3.6) with all fixes is available, you can update your local package.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, issue is closed. I see ChainSafe/web3.js on github contains fixes to underscore, and will be on NPM soon.

Also, `npm ls -all | grep underscore` shows this library is nested dependency at 2nd, 3rd and 4th levels. Appreciate link to npm-force-resolution on NPM for background, further instructions, and warning that cautions on possible security vulnerability. I have a sandboxed system for learning.