# npm audit fix vs npm install

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, npm-audit

There is something I don't understand with how `npm audit fix` works. From the [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-audit):

> `npm audit fix` runs a full-fledged `npm install` under the hood

So why when I run `npm install` and see audit vulnerabilities do I have to run `npm audit fix` manually to fix them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`npm install` without any arguments will just install the dependencies in your `package-lock.json` (assuming it exists). `npm audit fix` will use the audit information to figure out what dependencies need to be upgraded and install them, as long as they don't conflict with your `package.json`.

Comment: As far as I know, `npm install` install dependencies in `package.json` and `npm ci` install dependencies in `package-lock.json`. So what is the difference between `npm install` and `npm ci`?

Comment: Moreover, if I have both `package.json` and `package-lock.json` and manually change the `package.json` and run `npm install` it will use the new version from `package.json` that I've just edited...

Comment: @nrofis see here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52499617/2422776