# azure app service ('bf' is not recognized as an internal or external command)

Tags: azure-web-app-service, botframework

I have an issue with using **["@microsoft/botframework-cli": "^4.14.1"]** library in my nodejs project. Below is my sample snippet of my project. I'm just executing few bf commands with help from node-cmd library.

```
const http = require('http');
const shell = require('node-cmd');
const server = http.createServer(async (req, res) => {
  cmd = `bf orchestrator:basemodel:get --out ./model`
  await shell.runSync(cmd);
  res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  res.end("Process completed");
});
const port = process.env.PORT || 1337;
server.listen(port);
console.log('SERVER RUNNING AT',port);
```

The above code works fine in my local. But when i deploy the same code to azure web app, i'm getting

```
'bf' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

I navigated to the KUDU editor and checked if botframework node_modules are installed properly. Library was installed correctly though. I Even tried with Azure functions. But its still the same.
Please help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `npm install` reads `package.json` to create a list of dependencies and uses `package-lock.json` to inform which versions of these dependencies to install. **If a dependency is not in** `package-lock.json` **it will be added by** `npm install`.

`npm ci` (named after **C**ontinuous **I**ntegration) installs dependencies directly from `package-lock.json` and uses `package.json` only to validate that there are no mismatched versions. **If any dependencies are missing or have incompatible versions, it will throw an error**. Check [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-ci)

Instead of using `npm install` You can use the `npm ci`

```
"scripts": {
    "install": "npm ci",
}
```

or

```
"scripts": {
    "install": "npm ci @microsoft/botframework-cli",
}
```

Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53325242/15997690)