# Does Firebase Functions CLI deploy install dependencies?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, github-actions

When deploying a Node.js function using the firebase CLI are the `node_packages` uploaded or are they installed in the cloud based on the `package.json` (or `lock` file)?

I am trying to set up a CI flow in GitHub actions using the CLI and the functions doesn't seem to find the dependencies. Do I perhaps need to use the `predeploy` option in `firebase.json` to install the dependencies using `npm ci`?

Thanks!

Comment: If a package-lock.json or yarn.lock file is found within your project, that lock file will be respected when dependencies are installed using npm ci or yarn install.please refer this [document1](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/specifying-dependencies-nodejs) & [document2](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/handle-dependencies)

Comment: Thanks for your response, read that also in the docs but for me its still unclear wether I need to explicitly call npm ci in the predeploy options or if this is done automatically in the cloud?

Comment: I think it is better to run `npm ci` .This way you can ensure that your pipeline uses exactly the same dependencies you last used locally and can confirm that they worked for you.check this stackoverflow [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69459919/what-exactly-does-npm-ci-command-does-why-is-it-used-in-all-ci-pipelines-inste) &  [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52499617/what-is-the-difference-between-npm-install-and-npm-ci)

Comment: Thanks for your input, yes npm ci is the better option

Comment: I have provided an answer below,so that others could spot the workaround easier.please check

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use `npm ci` .This way you can ensure that your pipeline uses exactly the same dependencies you last used locally and can confirm that they worked for you

`npm ci` performs a clean install of all the dependencies of your app and it  is great for ci/cd pipelines and docker builds!

You can also check this stackoverflow [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69459919) & [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52499617) for more information