# Why npm installation decrease dependencies versions

Tags: javascript, npm, project, package.json

I have a problem while installing package using `npm` it is decreasing dependencies versions that breaks my application and unit tests, for example my `package.lock` file fater instalation looks like:
[image: package.lock]
Please tell me how can I install package without decreasing dependencies versions ?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52499617/what-is-the-difference-between-npm-install-and-npm-ci/53325242#53325242

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to use `npm ci`:

> In short, the main differences between using npm install and npm ci are:
>
> - The project must have an existing package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json.
> - **If dependencies in the package lock do not match those in package.json, npm ci will exit with an error, instead of updating the package lock**.
> - npm ci can only install entire projects at a time: individual dependencies cannot be added with this command.
> - If a node_modules is already present, it will be automatically removed before npm ci begins its install.
> - **It will never write to package.json or any of the package-locks: installs are essentially frozen.**

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-ci