# Why 'npm ci' is faster than 'npm install'?

Tags: node.js, npm, build, npm-install

I've researched for differences 'npm ci' and 'npm install'. but I haven't found the clear answer(they don't mention something clearly) of 'why npm ci is faster than npm'.

`npm ci` just install dependencies of package-lock.json and throw an error if there is a problem. but `npm install` install dependencies and updating dependencies and do something more if it needs. so `npm install` does do much more than `npm ci` does.

In my thoughts, That is why `npm ci` is faster than `npm install`.

But I'm not sure about it so I want more clear answers of yours.

Comment: Shouldn't you be comparing `npx ci` vs `npm ci`? The same way as to comparing `npx install` vs `npm install`? If I'm not mistaken npx redownloads the packages everytime so in theory npm would have been faster than npx on the subsequent calls..

Comment: @reikyoushin thanks for pointing it out. I misspelled it. I should've written `npm` not `npx`.

Comment: not an answer but related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52499617/what-is-the-difference-between-npm-install-and-npm-ci