# Dockerfile appears to build Angular but then cannot find the files it has created, what am I missing?

Tags: angular, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am currently trying to build a Dockerfile to build out my front end Angular application.

I have followed a tutorial and all the steps appear to be working until it needs to reference the built files that would normally be in the dist folder.

Anyone have any idea why these files are inaccessible?

```
FROM node:18.16.0 

# Copy dependency definitions
COPY package.json /app/
WORKDIR /app

# Run npm clean install, including dev dependencies for @angular-devkit
RUN npm install
RUN npm ci
# Run npm install @angular/cli
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli
# Copy all files
COPY . .
# Run ng build through npm to create dist folder
RUN ng build

# copy artifact build from the 'build environment'
COPY dist /app/public
COPY express /app
COPY src/assets /app/environments
COPY start /app

# Default environment variable for local testing
EXPOSE 80

# serve the appliction
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/app/start.sh"]

CMD [ "/bin/sh", "-c" , "/app/start.sh"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your question you did not specify which files are "inaccessible" and where you expect them to be. But your `Dockerfile` has some suspicious statements which won't work like you seem to expect them to work, e.g.:

```docker
RUN ng build

COPY dist /app/public
```

So you seemingly want to copy the results of `ng build` from the `dist` directory to `/app/public`.

But the [`COPY` command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) actually copies files from the [build context](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/context/) *into* the image, i.e., (in most cases) your current directory *on the host*!

What you want to do instead is to copy/move the files *within* the container, so you should be using the [`RUN` command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run):

```docker
RUN ng build

RUN mv dist /app/public/
```

(An even better solution would probably be to configure your `ng build` such that it places the build results in `public/` automatically)

Furthermore:

```docker
COPY start /app

# [...]

RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/app/start.sh"]
CMD [ "/bin/sh", "-c" , "/app/start.sh"]
```

The first command would copy a file `start` from the build context as `/app/start` into the image, but the latter commands reference a file `/app/start.sh`, so the file names seem to be wrong here.
Also: have a look into the [`--chmod=` flag of the `COPY` command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy).

---

Besides answering your question, here are some more comments on possible best practices:

```
RUN npm install
RUN npm ci
```

[`npm ci`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/commands/npm-ci) will install the same packages again. You should only use one or the other. For building a docker image `npm ci` is recommended; but then you also need to add the `package-lock.json` earlier:

```
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json package-lock.json .

RUN npm ci
```

See also [What is the difference between "npm install" and "npm ci"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52499617/what-is-the-difference-between-npm-install-and-npm-ci)

Then:

```
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Better: include `@angular/cli` in your installed packages in `package.json`/`package-lock.json`. That way you can pin the version of the package and make the build more reproducible - and `@angular/cli` may be already included in your installed packages anyway.

You can then run the build using [`npx`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/commands/npx) with `npx ng build`, or when configured as [`npm` script](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/using-npm/scripts) with `npm run build`.

```
COPY . .
```

This will copy all files from the *build context* into the image. This should make all subsequent `COPY`s redundant because all files then are *already* included in the image, e.g., `start`/`start.sh`, too.

Answer (score 0):

In your Dockerfile you have the following entry:

```bash
WORKDIR /app
```

This command in docker file will create a folder names `app` and all the relevant commands (`CMD`, `COPY`, `RUN` etc) will run under this folder.

```bash
# Copy all files
COPY . .
# Run ng build through npm to create dist folder
RUN ng build

# copy artifact build from the 'build environment'
COPY dist /app/public
COPY express /app
COPY src/assets /app/environments
COPY start /app
```

In the above code snippet you are copying `COPY . .` which will copy all the files from the current folder to the container.

You are first executing `ng build` **but** your sources are copied after this line, so i wonder what are you building with `ng build`

Comment: Using ng build to populate the dist folder, after that dist folder is populated I want it copied to the /app/public folder. Is this the wrong order?

Comment: `COPY` copies files from the host system, not earlier in the build.  Do you need to `RUN mv ...` the files instead?