# Same node version, same npm version but different package.lock file

Tags: reactjs, node.js, npm

We have a react project. We are using the same node version (18.16.1) and the same npm version (9.5.1) as a whole team. When I run npm install after cloning the repo, I get a different package-lock file. Why is that happening?

One of the differences:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52499617/what-is-the-difference-between-npm-install-and-npm-ci).

To summarize, `npm install` is not guaranteed to be a deterministic, reproducible build. If you want exact reproducibility, you should use `npm ci` to install dependencies.

Your `package-lock.json` is automatically generated/updated when you install or update dependencies, and reflects the currently installed packages for that project. So the reason the `package-lock.json` is different across machines is due to the nondeterminism of `npm install`.

Comment: @UfukUYSAL glad I could help! If that solved your problem, remember to accept!

Comment: But what if i install new package?

Answer (score 0):

@a.deshpande012's answer was okay when I did install but IMHO,  probably it was going to give another error if I install another package.

The fix was aligning ***.npmrc*** file with others.